# ffmpeg lossless mp4 to image sequence conversion (and back to mp4 again)

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I've browsed google for hours now and cant find anything about this.
I'm really struggling to extract the frames of an mp4 to an image sequence without any quality loss.
I need to be able to convert the image sequence back to an mp4 again also with no quality loss.
My purpose for this is to essentially drop half of all frames, making a 60fps mp4 into 30fps.
Previously the only other way I've found of doing this was to create a rawbitstream which takes up an absurd amount of disk space, and I don't want that. You can find that post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/573747/drop-every-even-or-odd-frames-using-ffmpeg). Anything that can help me achieve this, I would greatly appreciate if you could share it.

Comment: This is the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). The real question seems to be "How to go from frame rate of 60 to 30 without re-encoding?".

Comment: Hm, yes you seem to be right with the XY problem. However, dropping frames when converting to an image sequence proved to be very effective, the only issue being during the mp4 to image sequence conversion, original quality of the frames are lost. If that can be solved it will be an effective solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. Output images

TIFF is a lossless image format that can support YUV colorspace:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 images_%04d.tif
```

### 2. Encode video

#### Lossy (but you may not notice)

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i images_%04d.tif -crf 17 -vf format=yuv420p output.mp4
```

- Technically not lossless, but given enough bits it can reduce effects from [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss) and can look "visually lossless". This is what users usually actually want when they say they want "no loss".
- This assumes your files are in continuous sequential order. If not, then you can use `ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i "*.tif" ...` on Linux/macOS.

#### Lossless

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i images_%04d.tif -crf 0 output.mp4
```

- File size will be **huge** because it is lossless, and your player may not like it.
- This assumes your files are in continuous sequential order. If not, then you can use `ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i "*.tif" ...` on Linux/macOS.

---

### More info

- [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)
- [Image demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1)
- [Image muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2)

Comment: Thanks for your answer although it only contains conversion from images to mp4 and not from mp4 to images. Yes visually lossless is more of what I actually meant, sorry for not being clear about that.

Comment: @CinderellaCostallas Updated answer with TIFF example.